# How do I set a javascript variable inside a for loop to be used afterwards

Tags: javascript

So, I'm creating a login form, and when certain criteria aren't met to continue after the form, I am setting a variable to be tested after I've tested all the criteria. IF that variable ($cantcontinue) is set to 'true' I want to send a console message with the criteria that isn't met. Here is my code:

```
  function testfields() {
    // Ask if logging in or Creating Account
    //Logging In:
    if (document.getElementById("tEmail").style.display != "unset") {
      var loginelements = ["Username", "Password"];

      var text = "";
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < loginelements.length; i++) {

        //Check all fields are full:
        if (document.getElementById(loginelements[i]).value == "") {
          document.getElementById(loginelements[i]).style.background = '#ff6060'
          var cantcontinue = true;
          console.log(loginelements[i] + " is not set,")
        } else {
          document.getElementById(loginelements[i]).style.background = '#f7f7f7'
        }
      }
      if ($cantcontinue != true) {
        console.log("Create Account")
      } else {
        console.log("Could Not Create Account")
      }



    //Create a new Account:
    } else {
      var createelements = ["Username", "Password", "tEmaili", "tConfirmi"];

      var text = "";
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < createelements.length; i++) {

        //Check all fields are full:
        if (document.getElementById(createelements[i]).value == "") {
          document.getElementById(createelements[i]).style.background = '#ff6060'
          var cantcontinue = true;
          console.log(createelements[i] + " is not set,")
        } else {
          document.getElementById(createelements[i]).style.background = '#f7f7f7'
        }
      }

      //If passwords Match
      if (document.getElementById("Password").value != document.getElementById("tConfirmi").value) {
        var cantcontinue = true;
        document.getElementById("tConfirmi").style.background = '#ff6060'
        document.getElementById("tConfirmi").value = ''
        console.log(" Passwords didn't Match,");
      }

      if ($cantcontinue != true) {
        console.log("Create Account")
      } else {
        console.log("Could Not Create Account")
      }
    }        
  }
```

Comment: You should avoid defining a variable twice in the same scope / function (e.g. "var cantcontinue"). Best practice is to put all the variable definitions on top after the second line. :) Read more about "hoisiting" here https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch4.md or search for this term here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$cantcontinue !== cantcontinue;//....
```

Also

```
if (cantcontinue != true) {
```

equals:

```
if (!cantcontinue) {
```

Sidenote: Please don't use "$" unless you're using jQuery. It reminds me of PHP ( brrrrr...)

Comment: Thanks, I just got in the habit of using the $ because I have been using php a bit lately. Thanks man!